# How to pass runbook parameters from mvc website c# code to azure portal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-runbook

I have MVC website in which I have called Runbook from Webhook Uri but now I want to pass input parameters to runbook.
Following code I wrote to call runbook and pass parameters but parameters are going in Webhookdata instead of going as inputs.

```
using(var client = new HttpClient()) {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://s2events.azure-automation.net/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // HTTP POST
    var parameters = new InputParam() {
      subscriptionId = mSubscriptnId,
      resourceGrpName = vMachine.ResourceGroupName,
      vmssName = vMachine.Name,
      vmssInstanceId = vMachine.InstanceId,
      action = vmssInstanceAction,
      count = "5"
    };

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(mWebhookUri, parameters).Result;

    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
      Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer.
We have to use that webhook-data to fetch out input parameters.
Check code below to get input parameters from runbook script.

```
Param 
(    
    [object] $WebhookData,
)

# Get the data object from WebhookData.
$WebhookBody = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebhookData.RequestBody)

$subscriptionId = $WebhookBody.subscriptionId
$resourceGrpName = $WebhookBody.resourceGrpName
$vmssName = $WebhookBody.vmssName
$vmssInstanceId = $WebhookBody.vmssInstanceId
$action = $WebhookBody.action
$count = $WebhookBody.count
```